# How to set dynamic argument in Helm chats

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using helm chart for my kubernetes deployment as it is easy to set arguments in Helm as compared to kubernetes.

I had one Argument set in my kubernetes deployment file

```
args : ['--country=USA']
```

How to set these parameter in values.yaml file and then in deployment file of helm chart so that I can run the helm install command with parameters

`helm install --set country='London' -f helm/values.yaml helm`

This command I am trying to pass the arguments but it's still taking the old values.

Can anyone tell me how to do it and what changes should I make in values.yaml and in my deployment file

Answer (score 1):

So for a command like this

```sh
helm install --set country='England' mychart ./helmchart
```

You would have a values.yaml looking something like this

```yaml
country: USA
```

And a deployment template containing

```yaml
args: ['--country={{ .Values.country }}']
```

---

**Edit**: As discussed in the comments, if you want the number of arguments, and their names, to be set dynamically, you can instead do something like this

```sh
helm install --set cliargs='country=England city=London'
```

with a values.yaml

```yaml
cliargs: ""
```

and a deployment template containing

```yaml
args: ["{{ .Values.cliargs }}"]
```

---

Check helm.sh/docs for more details. This is all explained there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Can you tell me if the I can pass the both the key:value from the command line. for eg: country is also not fixed and many more arguments needs to be passed in this scenario how it can be done.

Comment: helm install --set 'country=England city=London'  mychart ./helmchart. If no of parametes are not fixed how it has to be set it in values.yaml and deployement files

Comment: Yes, just add more `--set`'s. E.g. `--set country=England --set city=London` Alternatively you can put them into yet another yaml file (let's call it overrides.yaml) and pass `-f overrides.yaml`

Comment: ok. so I dont need to set in yaml files or values file? as no of parameters are fixed. sometimes it will be 2 or 4. What should I set in deployment file for this line args: ['--country={{ .Values.country }}'] as it is just setting value for country. I want something like args:[{.$args}] and this $args should be taken from paramets set in --set via command line

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood then. Every value you `--set` must be explicitly used in the templates. I guess you want something like `--set cliargs='country=England city=London'` and then `args: ['{{ .Values.cliargs }}']` in the deployment template?

Comment: got it, so in 'values.yml' file, what should I add for cliargs or it should be blank?

Comment: It depends. It can be blank (so just `cliargs: ""`), or it can be some defaults you find sensible. They will be used if someone does `helm install` without setting cliargs.

Comment: ok. got it. I will try it once and accept the answer. Thank you for your help